# kubernetes rolling update using helm

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I am new to Helm. I have installed Minikube & Helm on my windows system. I am able create pods using Helm and  see deployment,pods & replicaset in dashboard.

I want to do rolling update using Helm. Guide me how to do rolling update in K8s using Helm.

Creating Tomcat pod using Helm

> helm create hello-world

Changed image name and deployment name in deployment.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mytomcat
spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: tomcat
```

Install

> helm install hello-world

```
NAME:   whopping-dolphin
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Aug 30 21:38:42 2017
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Service
NAME                          CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)  AGE
whopping-dolphin-hello-world  10.0.0.178  <none>       80/TCP   0s

==> v1beta1/Deployment
NAME      DESIRED  CURRENT  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
mytomcat  1        1        1           0          0s


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=hello-world,release=whopping-dolphin" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

**I see mytomcat deployment and pod mytomcat-2768693561-hd2hd in dashboard.**

Now I would like to give command which will delete my current deployment & pod in k8s and it should create new deployment and pod.

It will be helpful if I get  sample commands and yaml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below command is working fine for Rolling update.

1. First time it will be install
2. next time it will be upgrade

> helm upgrade --install tom-release --set appName=mytomcatcon 
>   hello-world

tom-release is my release name and passing runtime values to helm chart using --set option

Comment: this does not redeploy the image with the latest image, even when ImagePullPolicy set to always. Any way to do that too?

Comment: For me it do the upgrade, but with no zero downtime.

Comment: According to the official doc, it is a Recreate strategy, not a RollingUpdate. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy

Comment: my deployment not recreate using rolling update. any solutions for zero downtime using rolling update?